# Calculate accuracy of georeferencing

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, thin-plate-splines

I'm working on georeferencing old maps for archaeological purpose. Of course, colonial maps all do have some degree of transformation needed. But sometimes a specific region is well mapped while the neighbouring one is not. So I wonder if there is a way to calculate the amount of (in)accuracy, or the level to which the original image has been transformed in order to fit the actual landscape? Could a new raster be generated with these values? I'm using QGIS and TPS for georeferencing, but it can be on any platform.

Comment: as far as i remember, the accuracy is normally calculated from the ground control points, not the image itself. i dont know what qgis plugin you are using, but it seems the  https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html includes the residual as well as the mean error for the GCPs (figure 1)

Comment: So the overall accuracy is expressed by the global mean error, and each GCP has its own residual. I could compare two maps with the same control points, and see which one is more or less accurate. But how could I use these values to analyze a single map? Split it into tiles maybe?

Comment: There's a piece of software written by Bernhard Jenny for analysing the accuracy of old maps, see: http://mapanalyst.org/index.html. I don't know if this will help.

Comment: It looks very promising! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use georeferencer, it will (according to your settings) automatically or on-demand (via the File menu) save your GCP table to a file with extension `.points`. This includes the error as `deltaX` and `deltaY` values, as well as the residual.

The `.points` file is just a CSV file. You could post-process it in a spreadsheet application, or even within QGIS, loading it as a delimited text layer with the `mapX` and `mapY` columns indicating the geometry in your map's CRS.

So far so good. However, the deltas and the residual are computed as the *error* remaining *after* applying the chosen georeferencing transformation, while it sounds you want something representing the quantum of transformation actually applied. In particular, if you use the thin plate spline transformation type, due to the local corrections applied, your residuals will typically be miniscule.

What you could do is define your GCPs, and then *temporarily* set the transformation type to `Polynomial 1`, `Helmert` or `Projective`. Export the `.points` file. The errors therein will now reflect how much your map deviates from quasi-linearity around each GCP. More precisely, it specifies how much that particular GCP needs to be displaced versus a overall-error-minimizing linear-like transformation of all the GCPs, which is not quite the same thing but as good as you're going to get. In particular, a nonlinear "error" in one point, while all the others would be perfect, would result in an averaged-out mapping that would (undesirably) shift all the other perfect points a little bit too. If you're concerned about this, you may need to proceed iteratively and remove GCPs that are most highly out of whack.

You will need a pretty dense mesh of GCPs.

Then set the transformation type to Thin plate spline to actually get QGIS to smooth out those nonlinearities and give you a good georeferenced version of the map.

Finally, if you want to tie back those "nonlinear" deviations to the new, thin-plate-spline map representations of the GCPs, you could load up both `.points` files as layers and use the `pixelX` or `pixelY` fields to join them. Conceptually, it's both the `pixelX` and `pixelY` fields that should match to have the same point, but in practice either one will probably uniquely identify a GCP, and so a join on one of the fields should be good enough.

As to which of the 3 linear-like algorithms you choose temporarily, consult https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html#available-transformation-algorithms for a more detailed description. I suspect `Polynomial 1` will be the best choice unless you photographed the old maps obliquely, in which case `Projective`.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but when you load a map with 4 or more calibration points in MAPC2MAPC, it calculates a best-fit affine transformation between coordinates and pixels - and then reports on how good the fit is.

If you have an image and a suitable calibration file it will only take seconds.

But what to do if the calibration is 'off' is another matter!

http://www.the-thorns.org.uk/mapping/help/errors.html

Comment: You should add that you are the author of the program.

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".

Answer (score -1):

Load the maps shapefile from a trusted source  and compare them. If there is some error  it can be further improved by taking more control points, changing transformation parameters and trying a different datum.

Comment: [@Damini Jain](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/126827/damini-jain), I think it is not that easy to find archaeological shapefiles from a trusted source. I assume it could more efficient to find archaeological web map service (WMS, TMS/WMTS etc.) and use it as a background map.

Comment: There are many sites of government and sources from where you can get it. You have to look on the Internet.  So my answer isn't wrong.

Comment: @DaminiJain, thanks, but georeferencing itself is not the problem. I'm looking for a way to evaluate the degree of transformation of the original image, like on a raster calculation. If it matches archaeological sites or not will be a question for later.

Comment: @gvanhavre http://geog.uoregon.edu/amarcus/geog418/Labs/Lab06_rectification.htm hope this helps.